# How to do a comparaison from an array of comparators ['<', '<=', '>', '>=']?

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE**

The idea here is to filter out numbers say less than 10 or (less than or equal to 10) or greater that 10 or (greater than or equal to 10).

So as the user inputs a  value like this show me all nums less than or equal to 10 (the input will be `<=10` )

The idea is to filter out numbers from an array using comparisons, when a particular one is matched

**REM** v is supposed to be like this <5 or <10 or <=3 or <=2 or >5 or >=6 and so on...

```
nums.filter(num => {
    return comparisions.map(operation => {
        if (v.startsWith('>'))
        return num > parseInt(v.replace('>', '').trim());

        if (v.startsWith('>='))
        return num >= parseInt(v.replace('>=', '').trim());

        if (v.startsWith('<='))
        return num <= parseInt(v.replace('<=', '').trim());

        if (v.startsWith('<'))
        return num < parseInt(v.replace('<', '').trim());
    })
})
```

instead of above repetition how can I consolidate it in to the following function?

```
const comparisions = ['<', '<=', '>', '>=']

const nums = [3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 10]
// here I've shown only few a numbers for simplicity. In real it is a big array of nos.

nums.filter(num => {
    return comparisions.map(operation => {
        if (v.startsWith(operation))
        return num operation parseInt(v.replace(operation, '').trim());
    })
})
```

```
//example v = '<=10'
```

**UPDATE** no eval()s please. I'm not a fan of evals.

Comment: that's a nice question.

Comment: create an object map mapping to arrow functions returning true or false based on comparisons?  You could also use eval, or a combo of both I guess.

Comment: I'm confused by your example code. The top attempt doesn't seem to work with two arrays like the lower code. What is the input? And why are there 4 operators for 6 numbers? I'd expect 5 operators.

Comment: I've updated the brief.

Comment: what's v supposed to be?

Comment: @user120242 can you show me some code.

Comment: v is supposed to be like this <5 or <10 or <=3 or <=2 or >5 or >=6 and so on...

Comment: This is the code. It is straight forward. Just imagine possibilities in these forms <5 or <10 or <=3 or <=2 or >5 or >=6. It can be any number that starts with with a comparator in front of it.

Comment: Why not a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch]) ?

Comment: But it will be repetition.  Right? Instead I want to consolidate in to a simple function.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 3):

Build an object map of operations to comparison functions.  Use it to filter.

Assumes v always matches "[matches to a key in comparisons][digits]"

```js
const comparisions = {
  '<':  (x, y) => x < y,
  '<=': (x, y) => x <= y,
  '>':  (x, y) => x > y,
  '>=': (x, y) => x >= y
}
// you could also build functions that evaluate using eval or Function constructor based on the key(< or <= etc) provided

const nums = [3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 10]

v = "<=3"

console.log(
  nums.filter(num => {
    const [, op, n] = v.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/)
    return comparisions[op](num, n)
  })
)
```

Comment: I was planning to do it like this. Just wonder if there are any other alternatives excluding eval(). That's why i posted question. thank you for your time.

Comment: You can try to hold out and hope someone comes up with something.  But, it shouldn't be possible by definition, as I've tried to explain in the comments in the other answer.  It would help for you to clarify the actual full use case for this.

Comment: I don't know if it will represent what you want, but a template tag might be another option, but again I don't know your full use case, so I don't know if that would really be helpful.  Generally something like <= 10 or a function is already concise enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval like this :

```
let cmp = (input,op)=>(`${op}${input}`);
console.log(eval(`${1}${cmp(3,'<')}`)); // is 1 < 3 ?
```

Comment: can you please suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: @reacggarav What is the security risk of ```eval``` here?

Comment: @reacggarav just use a regexp to only allow the operators you want

Comment: Some issues that I cannot disclose. For security reasons this is not recommended. That's why. Don't feel bad/.

Comment: Tell me what is the security risk, please.

Comment: If you need dynamic evaluation of arbitrary statements or logic you won't be able to avoid eval.  If you need it to be restricted, you need logic to make it more restrictive.  This is by definition and unavoidable.

Comment: It;s not secure. So it is not commonly recommended using it. Please don't go further in to that. Kindly concentrate on this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!
Show me which one is here.

Comment: To illustrate the point:  If I say "Tell me if x is [...] than y".  I need to interpret [...] somehow.  Either I already know how to translate [...] to "some operation" with pre-existing knowledge that I have, or I have to take [...] and "run it" without understanding what [...] means and just trust that it does what it's supposed to.

Comment: @user120242 answers demos this. This is somewhat similar.

Comment: @user120242 I wrote the ```cmp``` function for this reason instead direct. You can validate in that f..ing function then pass to eval.

Comment: I gave an answer that matches what you want, but... I'm trying to help you understand something important and that cybercoder is trying to imply in reference to security:   For example, it's impossible to ask an elementary student to tell me if x is a derivative of x^2.  I could tell the student, just -1 to the exponent, and "just do exactly what I say every time I give you a problem".  That's like using eval.  So then you ask, is it safe to have the kid just do whatever I say every time?  What if I tell the kid to write a swear on his paper or something completely wrong?

Comment: That won't happen, because the context of what the student will do is restricted.  I can't ask him to do _anything_ I tell him to, because his own upbringing will tell him not to.  In this case the domain for what eval can be given is highly restricted, so it is not an issue.  Hence cybercoder's reference to "what is the security issue"

Comment: My solution is equivalent to just saying:  "if you see an exponent, just minus 1 every time".  If he sees anything different, he won't know what to do.  These are the limitations and possibilities, by definition.

Comment: The alternative is to teach him calculus.  Which would probably be the equivalent to a math library of some sort to evaluate these expressions safely.  Or perhaps maybe equivalent to giving him a calculator that solves derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a package like [jexl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jexl), that can be used to evaluate expressions, but it could be an "overkill" solution.

But using jexl, for example, you would only have to do this:

```
nums.filter(num => jexl.evalSync(`${num}${v}`))
```

Comment: I think you didn't get it. Please go through the brief once more.

Comment: If you are talking about "no eval()s please. I'm not a fan of evals.", it has been added when I was writing my answer.